Only special permutations result in a constant expression when permuting coefficients in a sum involving binomials?
Fix $n\geq 1$ and let $p_k(x) := x^k(x-1)^{n-k}$.
Suppose $\pi$ is a permutation on $\{0,1,\dotsc,n\}$, such that
$$
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^k \binom{n}{k} p_{\pi(k)}(x) \text{ is a constant}.
$$
Must it be the case that $\{\pi(j),\pi(n-j)\} = \{j,n-j\}$ for all $j$ if $n$ is even,
and $\pi$ is either the identity permutation or the permutation that sends $j \to n-j$
whenever $n$ is odd?
How would one go about to prove this?
As a start, by putting $x=0$ and $x=1$, one can see that $\{\pi(0),\pi(n)\} = \{0,n\}$, but how can one (in a preferably elegant manner) prove the full statement?

Have you tested this on all permutations up to some small length?

The polynomials $p_k(x)$ are linearly independent over the rationals,
so they form a basis for the space of all polynomials of degree at
most $n$.. Hence there are unique rational numbers $a_k$ for which
$\sum a_kp_k(x)=1$, and for any $c\in\mathbb{Q}$ the relation $\sum
ca_kp_k(x)=c$ is the unique linear combination of the $p_k(x)$'s equal
to $c$. The proof now follows from the fact that $\sum (-1)^k{n\choose
k}p_k(x) =(-1)^n$.

Ah, i knew there was a smart solution, I was too blind for this obvious fact! This is what I get for dabbling in complex dynamical systems...
